# How can I build and test a REST API to spec if I don't have access to the database it's specced to?

Tags: python, database, api, http, rest

I need to write a REST API (I'm writing it in Python, for what it's worth) that GETs, POSTs, and PUTs to a database - the only problem is the database doesn't exist, or I don't have access to it.  How can I emulate or create a very simple database to use as I build and test the API?

Comment: Are you using a framework such as Django or Pyramid?

Comment: I hadn't gotten that far yet.  Do I need to use a framework, necessarily?

Comment: Not necessarily, but I find [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) with the [Django REST Framework](http://django-rest-framework.org/) quite nice.

Comment: @yoel I have been using Flask to develop RESTFUL services and highly recommend it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sqlite http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html. If you are using an ORM like SQLAlchemy (http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) you can initially start using sqlite and later switch to a db such as MySQL or PGSql.